# How to click button which doesn't have button tag, getting InvalidArgumentException on clicking the input tag

Tags: selenium-webdriver

[image]I am trying to click on choose file button on my web application, but getting 
"Invalid argument " exception : Cannot click  elements

```
1584522811772 addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org WARN Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid extension permission: mozillaAddons

1584522811772 addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org WARN Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid extension permission: telemetry

1584522811772 addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org WARN Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid extension permission: resource://pdf.js/

1584522811772 addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org WARN Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid extension permission: about:reader*

JavaScript error: resource://gre/modules/XULStore.jsm, line 66: Error: Can't find profile directory.

1584522814417 Marionette INFO Listening on port 25414

1584522814453 Marionette WARN TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session

Mar 18, 2020 2:43:34 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession

INFO: Detected dialect: W3C

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: Cannot click <input type=file> elements

Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'

System info: host: 'RSOMWANSHI2L1', ip: '10.85.97.92', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_221'

Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver

Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, browserVersion: 73.0,
```

**WebDriver Code :**
package RealTimeExercise_E2E_Practise;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class FileUpload {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","E:\\Practise\\Drivers\\geckodriver.exe");
    //System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\\\\\\\Practise\\\\\\\\Drivers\\\\\\\\chromedriver.exe");
    //WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    driver.get("https://i5130-win8.ptcnet.ptc.com:8443/InService/delivery/activation/activation.jsp");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[.='Use activation packet file']//parent::div//input[@type='radio']")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='file']")).click();      
    //driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#file")).click();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    //Runtime.getRuntime().exec("E:\\AutoItScript\\UploadFile.exe");


}
```

}

**HTML :**

File Path

Comment: pleease add the code and html

Comment: which line are you getting the error at /

Comment: @line : driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='file']")).click(); -Line 21

Comment: please add the html, and you have to click the button element and not the input element. May be click action is not supported for that particular input element. Find element "Button" and click on it

Comment: Actually its not button its input file only :

Comment: <div class="activation-row">
 <div class="activation-cell activation-field-label ng-binding">
         File Path </div>
 <div class="activation-cell">
 <input type="file" name="file" id="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().setFile(this)" data-ng-model="formData.activationPacketFile" data-ng-required="formData.medium === 'file'" data-ng-disabled="formData.medium === 'web'" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-valid-required" disabled="disabled"</div></div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use browser actions,

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);

builder.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='file']"))).click().build().perform();
```

The input element may not support the click action that's why you are getting the invalid argument error.

Comment: Hey Thanks, it worked :) well....

Comment: @rashmisomwanshi could you upvote by clicking the up arrow icon near to my answerand accept the answer by clicking the tick sign near to my answer

Comment: done...Thank You

Comment: @PDHide - I had the same problem (Not able to click on "choose file") and could find solution only through your answer. Thank you so much and keep sharing your knowledge.